# Is there any sound desk software for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

A friend of mine is looking at putting on a small-scale dance show at a local pub. She has hired a few lights and a PA system with a mixing board. All her music is done through either an MP3 player or a laptop.

When I was in a show a while back, the sound dude was using a linux-based laptop to play samples off, essentially it played a sample the instant he clicked on a button on the screen.

From memory, the software's GUI consisted of a number of large blue (Although the color is probably modifiable) squares. Does anyone know what this might have been?

If not, is there anything similar anyone could suggest (Excluding of course, Banshee and Rhythmbox - Which I will probably use if it comes down to it)

Answer (score 0):

### Have you looked at Mixxx?

[image]

To Install
Open a terminal, and enter:

> ```
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mixxx/mixxx
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install mixxx libportaudio2
> ```

Or
Ubuntu also provides a version of Mixxx which can be installed directly from the Ubuntu Software Centre. This version is usually woefully out of date; therefore using the PPA is preferable maybe preferable.  You can download the PPA from [here](https://launchpad.net/~mixxx/+archive/mixxx).

It might do no harm to visit the [Mixxx Wiki page](http://www.mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php)

Comment: @StephenMyall: whould mind explaining the main difference between the above question and [my question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291039/is-there-any-file-manager-that-highlights-names-that-are-searched-for) so you vote to close one and answer the other?!