# Is there any File manager that highlights names that are searched for?

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, filemanager, dolphin

When in Chrome or other new web browsers, a word is searched in a page, all occurrences of the word is highlighted. I need a similar functionality for a File Manager. I tested Nautilus and Dolphin. I searched a word in a folder with a lot of files. But instead of highlighting the files with names containing that word; files with names not containing that word were hidden.

Is there any File Manager for Ubuntu or option that highlights names that are searched for (instead of hiding other files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try it on the command line with

```
find
```

It has a lot of options. See [the man page of find on Ubuntu Manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/find.1.html).

For example all the files in my current directory containing the letters 'auth'

```
find /home/frank -name '*auth*'
```

It's not GUI-based, but it has more options than any GUI-based filemanager. (Maybe Midnightcommander can do it too.)

```
grep
```

is also a possibility.

For example to find the string 'AskUbuntu' in all the files in my home directory:

```
grep -r "AskUbuntu" /home/frank
```

See [the man page of grep on Ubuntu Manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/grep.1.html)